# YUI Drag & Drop with two lists, save new lists to file

Tags: javascript, list, drag-and-drop, yui

What I want to do is have two draggable, sortable lists that after I reorder them, I can click 'Save' or 'Submit' that saves the new lists to a separate file. I'm new to YUI and a novice at PHP but what I'm having trouble with is trying to figure out how to export these lists with their new attributes (the class changes from 'list1' to 'list2').

I'm using the template from [YUI Blog](http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/3.2.0pr1/examples/dd/list-drag.html) but it's not exactly forthcoming with info.

Here's the relevant code from the sample (all I'm doing is basically changing some names from the template):

```
<div id="play">
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="list1">Item #1</li>
    <li class="list1">Item #2</li>
    <li class="list1">Item #3</li>
    <li class="list1">Item #4</li>
    <li class="list1">Item #5</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li class="list2">Item #1</li>
    <li class="list2">Item #2</li>
    <li class="list2">Item #3</li>
    <li class="list2">Item #4</li>
    <li class="list2">Item #5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
YUI().use('dd-constrain', 'dd-proxy', 'dd-drop', function(Y) {
//Listen for all drop:over events
Y.DD.DDM.on('drop:over', function(e) {
    //Get a reference to our drag and drop nodes
    var drag = e.drag.get('node'),
        drop = e.drop.get('node');

    //Are we dropping on a li node?
    if (drop.get('tagName').toLowerCase() === 'li') {
        //Are we not going up?
        if (!goingUp) {
            drop = drop.get('nextSibling');
        }
        //Add the node to this list
        e.drop.get('node').get('parentNode').insertBefore(drag, drop);
        //Resize this nodes shim, so we can drop on it later.
        e.drop.sizeShim();
    }
});
//Listen for all drag:drag events
Y.DD.DDM.on('drag:drag', function(e) {
    //Get the last y point
    var y = e.target.lastXY[1];
    //is it greater than the lastY var?
    if (y < lastY) {
        //We are going up
        goingUp = true;
    } else {
        //We are going down.
        goingUp = false;
    }
    //Cache for next check
    lastY = y;
});
//Listen for all drag:start events
Y.DD.DDM.on('drag:start', function(e) {
    //Get our drag object
    var drag = e.target;
    //Set some styles here
    drag.get('node').setStyle('opacity', '.25');
    drag.get('dragNode').set('innerHTML', drag.get('node').get('innerHTML'));
    drag.get('dragNode').setStyles({
        opacity: '.5',
        borderColor: drag.get('node').getStyle('borderColor'),
        backgroundColor: drag.get('node').getStyle('backgroundColor')
    });
});
//Listen for a drag:end events
Y.DD.DDM.on('drag:end', function(e) {
    var drag = e.target;
    //Put our styles back
    drag.get('node').setStyles({
        visibility: '',
        opacity: '1'
    });
});
//Listen for all drag:drophit events
Y.DD.DDM.on('drag:drophit', function(e) {
    var drop = e.drop.get('node'),
        drag = e.drag.get('node');

    //if we are not on an li, we must have been dropped on a ul
    if (drop.get('tagName').toLowerCase() !== 'li') {
        if (!drop.contains(drag)) {
            drop.appendChild(drag);
        }
    }
});

//Static Vars
var goingUp = false, lastY = 0;

//Get the list of li's in the lists and make them draggable
var lis = Y.Node.all('#play ul li');
lis.each(function(v, k) {
    var dd = new Y.DD.Drag({
        node: v,
        target: {
            padding: '0 0 0 20'
        }
    }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDProxy, {
        moveOnEnd: false
    }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDConstrained, {
        constrain2node: '#play'
    });
});

//Create simple targets for the 2 lists.
var uls = Y.Node.all('#play ul');
uls.each(function(v, k) {
    var tar = new Y.DD.Drop({
        node: v
    });
});

});
```